# sfdx force:source:pull fail with community member page layout

Tags: salesforcedx, source

I am receiving the following error message during a pull from my scratch org:

```
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'Layout' named 'null-Community Member Layout' cannot be found
```

It is easy to reproduce this:

1. create a default scratch org:
2. change something on the User's Community Member Layout, for example
   remove a field.
3. try to run sfdx force:source:pull

I am not sure if it is related to our configuration:

```
"orgName": "TestOrg",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities", "ContactsToMultipleAccounts", "ServiceCloud"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "socialProfilesEnable": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true
    },
    "opportunitySettings": {
      "enableOpportunityTeam": true
    },
    "entitlementSettings":{
      "enableEntitlements": true
    },
    "liveAgentSettings":{
      "enableLiveAgent": true
    },
    "omniChannelSettings":{
      "enableOmniChannel": true,
      "enableOmniSkillsRouting": true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really a solution, but you can .forceignore this file by adding this line:

```
null-Community Member Layout
```

It is important to do not specify the path of the file.